# shared memory programme is not working in c

Tags: c, unix, ipc

There are two programs are there one is call server which put content in shared memory and other is client which received a content from shared memory both in both programs it is attached successfully with shared memory but data is not display in client side.

Client.c

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
void main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
     int shmid=shmget(124,70,0777);
     char * data;
     printf("%d\n",shmid);  
     data=shmat(shmid,0,0);
     printf("%s",data);
}
```

Server.c

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
void main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    int shmid=shmget(124,70,0777|IPC_CREAT);
    char * data,*ptr;
    printf("%d\n",shmid);
    if((data=shmat(shmid,0,0))==(char *)-1);
    {
        printf("No attach\n");
    }
    ptr=data;
    memset(data,0,1024);
    printf("%s",data);
    char c[]="My name is milap pancholi";
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(c);i++)
    {
        printf("%c",c[i]);
        data+=c[i];
    }
    printf("%s\n",ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is this:

```
data+=c[i];
```

This does pointer arithmetic, advancing `data`, not what you want at all. Replace it with:

```
data[i] = c[i];
```

Other issues:

- `main` returns `int`, not void. Use `int main() { ... }` if you don't need the arguments count and values (to avoid warnings, which you should turn *way* up).
- You're missing `#include <stdio.h>` for `printf`
- You're missing `#include <string.h>` for `memset`